# Edit a driver for shape keys

Tags: drivers, shape-keys

I created a driver for shape keys of a lattice.

[image: Driver driven shape-key values]

Now i want to edit them, but i cant find them in the graph editor. I switched from F-Curve to Driver-editing, selected the object (even switched off the option to only show drivers of the currently selected object) and no driver appears in the graph editor. There must be something like right-click on the property and "edit driver", i just cant't find it

(Maybe important: The Lattice is parented to a mesh, but that shouldn't be a problem)